# Are Iranian citizens subject to their regime's laws on dress, etc., when they are publicly on view outside the country?

Tags: iran, islam

There have been countless images of female Iranian supporters dressed in party-hats and looking every bit as casually turned out as any Western women. In view of the recent severe, and brutal, actions inside Iran against women dressed in a way considered inappropriate, could this portend trouble for them when they return?

Equally, at the World Cup match against England, the entire Iranian team stood grim-faced and silent during the playing of their country's anthem. It has been widely interpreted by the media as a protest against the regime that rules in Tehran.

Comment: We cannot look in the future. Maybe, maybe not. But in a few days we will know. Iran isn't the nicest country on Earth, politically speaking.

Comment: Notably, [they did sing it before today's game against Wales](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/63753096).

Comment: @F1Krazy Not exactly with zest and commitment - but they did win the match, which may mean more to the Iranian regime.

Comment: The recent edit turned this into a "what does the law say?" question, which would fit much better on https://law.stackexchange.com. We generally only allow law questions when they are laws which apply specifically to politicians and political processes. See also [Where/how do we draw the line between legal and political questions?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/where-how-do-we-draw-the-line-between-legal-and-political-questions) on meta. Laws affecting political speech are a fringe-case, but I believe it still fits better on law SE.

Comment: @Philipp What I have for some while felt is needed is a "Current Affairs" site. The ethos of the politics site is constrained to pure political science. (At its worst this amounts to questions such as "What is the average age of a Member of Parliament?") There is no obvious avenue for applied political reflection.

Comment: The edit to this question seems to have turned it into a new question instead of just fixing problems with the existing question.

Comment: I don't think the question is totally out of scope, just premature. Currently any answer would be mostly speculation. However, once we know what happened, one can probably ask an interesting question about it. As for the current title. Typically a country do not have jurisdiction over another country, so before Iranians do return to Iran, nothing can happen. When they come back, many things can happen.

Comment: We can't tell what will happen to these people when they return home. That's pure speculation.

Comment: Q would be a lot less speculative minus **Will this put the footballers in any jeopardy?**.  Per the title:  are people liable for prosecution for dress law infractions abroad (I am pretty sure the soccer team isn't gonna get in trouble for hijab infraction either so they aren't that great a fit anyway).  We see prosecutions for infractions abroad in other countries.  Sometimes frivolous and nasty, like Singapore jailing ppl smoking weed abroad.  Sometimes quite understandable, like nations prosecuting their citizens for child abuse abroad.  What does Iran do? even extra-legally is reasonable.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica My question which has now been closed, reopened and closed again, did start off by asking that question. It occurred to me when the team were totally silent and grim-faced through the anthem, that surely this would get them in trouble. And after all the recent news of the brutal treatment of women not wearing the hijab, to see all those Iranian women enjoying themselves in coloured hats and face paint etc - just like European women - did seem odd. My thought was that they cannot have been oppressed to the extent that they have forgotten how to enjoy themselves.

Comment: OK, but the primary reason to have some concern is your explicit query on what's gonna happen to the football team, **in the future**.  I'd vote to reopen if you removed future event considerations which you know are off limit.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica See edits.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I've no doubt the footballers and possibly the fans as well,  will be forgiven everything if they manage to defeat the United States - the Great Satan -  in the final group match tonight!

Comment: Of course they are. But they aren't persecuted if they aren't famous and if there isn't any videos or pictures showing they were without scarves outside the country.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. One of the drawbacks of an authoritarian system of government is that what "the law" is is a bit more opaque. If the current ruling President of Iran (or the current Supreme Leader) wants to punish the players then the players will be punished. Who is there to overrule a leader who is Supreme?

You can argue however that similar traits exist even in much more democratic forms of government; if anyone from local prosecutors or police up the chain in the executive all the way up to the President has a beef with someone, they can do their best to disrupt that person's life using their power to do so. The biggest differences though are that 1) The people in the executive must generally still prove something to different officials in a completely different branch of government before any actions can be taken, 2) those same people are subject to the same set of laws, which (at least, theoretically) include harsh punishments for abusing their power against ordinary citizens. Additionally, many of the officials in the executive branch are elected, so in a not very long time they could potentially be held to account for their actions by the people generally, even if any actions they take against people don't rise to the level of criminal. This system of checks and balances against abuses of power just doesn't exist in authoritarian governments.

There have been examples of kidnappings of dissidents by some administrations while they are abroad and even sometimes go so far as outright murder. It is highly speculated that Russia even went so far as to use a chemical agent against defected spy [Sergei Skripal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Skripal) and his 33 year old daughter in order to either silence or exact revenge against, and U.S.-Saudi relations are still being impacted by the murder of [Jamal Khashoggi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamal_Khashoggi) by members of the Saudi royal family (which just so happened to also be audio recorded by the Turkish government).

The balancing act authoritarians must make when dispensing such justice is to find a way to keep the populace subdued enough out of fear and yet not angry enough to revolt, so disappearing the *entire* team is probably not something they can risk doing, certainly not in the wake of the recent protests in the country triggered by the death of [Mahsa Amini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahsa_Amini_protests) while in official custody. They may, however, choose to identify who amongst them is the most vocal and attempt to make an example of them personally or their family in an attempt to silence the entire team (or in this case induce into patriotically singing along), but the range of options the leaders of the country have and can use against any single individual is, in fact, supreme.

Comment: Not sure Skripal is that related, but this claim, that people may fear persecution due to unclear rules is substantiated by this a recent [rock climbing wo hijab event](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/10/18/irans-elnaz-rekabi-apologises-after-competing-without-hijab).  and a [female boxing competitor's concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadaf_Khadem#Reception)  Now, it might be argued that is Western propaganda - I did not find hijab-related prosecutions for women specifically *abroad* googling.  But Iran is a regime which **has** murdered expat dissidents in the past.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I wanted to highlight Skripal since a dangerous chemical agent was used and the fact that the entire levers of power in the state can be brought to bear against someone. Now I doubt any nuclear armed nation would utilize a nuclear warhead against domestic political opponents who happened to be traveling abroad, but if they have absolute power over those warheads and got it in their mind it was a good idea, who would stop them?

Comment: Also: I am not an expert in Iranian law, there may in fact be limits on the Supreme Leader's power to which I am ignorant. If there are and those limits can be substantiated, I invite anyone provide some source.

Comment: "those same people are subject to the same set of laws, which usually include harsh punishments for abusing their power against ordinary citizens." Empirically, this is not true.

Comment: @ohwilleke I really want to argue with that, but in my heart I know you're right.

Answer (score 4):

We have confirmation now.  The rockclimber who competed without a scarf about 6 weeks ago?

Her family house has been [demolished by the government](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-63847173).  Which claims it was unrelated.

I would also add that the change in behavior of the soccer team, between their first appearances - speech, no anthem - and subsequent avoidance of the subject and singing of the anthem again seems to strongly point to threats of consequences made between those 2 events.

Comment: One of the sources linked there says "Female athletes must also abide by the dress code when they are officially representing Iran in competitions abroad." So it's possible only female athletes who are representing Iran need to abide by the dress code.